# compare a input field value to a string or text symfony2

Tags: symfony

I was trying to learn about framework and Ill be starting under "Symfony", then i got this problem, I create a

```
{{ form_widget(form.type) }}
```

equivalent to

```
<input type="text" class="type" id="type"/>
```

this element "input" have a value that given by a tab or menu if i click on it, example jumping.how do i compare it to a text using "Symfony" if statement like the logic below.

```
{% if jumping == "text" %}
//it will do something
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as explained nicely in the symfony docs [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/forms.html#rendering-a-form-in-a-template) you need to use the `form.vars.value` to get the input field's value

so for someting like `{{ form_widget(form.name) }}` you would access the values by doing `{{ form.vars.value.name }}`

in your case it would be

```
{% if form.vars.value.name == "text" %}
   //do something
{% endif %}
```

Comment: There is no `===` comparator in Twig. If you want to check that they are "equal" use `==`, if you want identical use `is same as(value)`.